# Scaling html/css images for different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, image, scaling

First time user, with a simple but frustrating problem.

I am a new web coder, designing my website (austinwoehrle.net)

I am trying to make the banner of Seattle scale with my darker background, but if I zoom in, it breaks out of the div.

On smaller monitors the image will be too large to fit in the darker background.

I have already set the width to 100% and have tried a lot of trouble shooting!

Thanks for the help!
Again, my website is http://www.austinwoehrle.net/homepage.html

Comment: You say you have tried this: <img width="100%" src="seattle.jpg"> ? It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment you have this:

```
<div id="seattle" alt="test">
    <img src="seattle.jpg" width="620" height="210"> 
</div>
```

Change the width of your image to `width="100%"`. This may then be slightly wider than you want it, so you will want to add margin or padding to the containing `seattle` div on line 126 of `mystyle.css`

```
width:80%;
margin:0 10%;
```

Then alter your image to have a width of 100% and remove the height.

```
<img src="seattle.jpg" width="100%">
```

---

Notes

```
 margin:0 10%;
 //is equal to writing
 margin-top:0;
 margin-right:10%;
 margin-bottom:0;
 margin-left:10%;
```

Check out [this site](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-shorthand-properties.shtml) for information on how to write this.

Comment: I would remove the height attr on the image so that the height of the image automatically adapts to its new width.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!

"margin:0 10%;"
What does that do? Just curious as I am trying to learn.

Comment: @AustinWoehrle Hey Austin welcome to the site, check out my updated answer :)